# How to force ASan to show more than one callstack line deep?

Tags: c++, gcc, stack-trace, callstack, address-sanitizer

Currently when I ran my application I get next output:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/debug/vector:346:error: attempt to subscript container
    with out-of-bounds index 1, but container only holds 1 elements.

Objects involved in the operation:
sequence "this" @ 0x0x60400000fd30 {
  type = NSt7__debug6vectorIdSaIdEEE;
}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It is compiled with official ubuntu 14.04 gcc and compile flags:

`-fPIC -std=c++11 -fopenmp -Wall -pedantic -Wunused -O0 -g3 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage`

LLVM and clang are also installed out of the box and application is started like this:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.4 ./app
```

Why only one call stack line appears? How to get context that would be related to my application?

---

Note: if I run from under GDB

```
gdb ./app
run
where
```

I get readable call stack (with line numbers and call details).
(gdb) where

```
#0  0x00007ffff3640c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff3644028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff43c7fe5 in __gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_M_error() const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000000000427184 in std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator[] (this=0x60400000fd30,
    __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/debug/vector:346
#4  0x00007ffff47f6bfa in GeneralParameters::GeneralParameters...
```

yet I want to get call stack output without running gdb for each of my 100+ unit test applications - I want to see such errors directly on `ctest -VV` which runs all my tests in order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error comes not from ASan but from STL debug vector implementation. It won't give you much info about stacktrace but just abort execution (same as e.g. `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`).